Jsonb index in PostgreSQL was used but query is still very slow
I've created a index like this:
create index name_idx on transactions((details->>'name'));

However, when I query like this:
select count(*) from transactions where (details->>'name') in ('Tom', 'Ken', 'Cherry');

In the table, it has over millions rows. This query runs very slow but I explain the SQL it exactly used the index.
How can I improve the SQL?
The query takes around 2-3mins.
Here is query plan:
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=500691.85..500691.86 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=158421.546..158723.501 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(*)
  Buffers: shared hit=19078917 read=1643001
  ->  Gather  (cost=500691.64..500691.85 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=158389.403..158721.346 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=19078917 read=1643001
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=499691.64..499691.65 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=158034.608..158034.946 rows=1 loops=3)
              Output: PARTIAL count(*)
              Buffers: shared hit=19078917 read=1643001
              Worker 0:  actual time=157861.445..157861.673 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 5
                  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
                  Timing: Generation 2.171 ms, Inlining 231.577 ms, Optimization 35.146 ms, Emission 43.585 ms, Total 312.479 ms
                Buffers: shared hit=6376436 read=547834
              Worker 1:  actual time=157861.810..157862.080 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 5
                  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
                  Timing: Generation 1.931 ms, Inlining 230.618 ms, Optimization 36.129 ms, Emission 44.178 ms, Total 312.856 ms
                Buffers: shared hit=6375452 read=547682
              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.transactions t  (cost=2000.04..499504.94 rows=74679 width=0) (actual time=903.630..157497.724 rows=1706863 loops=3)
                    Recheck Cond: ((t.details ->> 'name'::text) = ANY ('{Tom, Cherry, Ken}'::text[]))
                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 88
                    Heap Blocks: exact=12348 lossy=327329
                    Buffers: shared hit=19078917 read=1643001
                    Worker 0:  actual time=749.550..157337.900 rows=1711896 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=6376436 read=547834
                    Worker 1:  actual time=749.524..157373.287 rows=1709957 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=6375452 read=547682
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test1_idx  (cost=0.00..1955.24 rows=179230 width=0) (actual time=956.688..956.689 rows=5120588 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((t.details ->> 'name'::text) = ANY ('{Tom, Cherry, Ken}'::text[]))
                          Buffers: shared hit=17 read=4313
Settings: search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'
Planning Time: 6.219 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 17
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 38.523 ms, Inlining 504.706 ms, Optimization 167.494 ms, Emission 203.509 ms, Total 914.232 ms
Execution Time: 158769.716 ms


How long is slow? Also can you edit the question to add the query plan you see?

@Dogbert added, pls see, thx

Your current plan has no timings at all. Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) ?

@FrankHeikens edited the question

Turn on track_io_timing to see how much of the time is going to IO.

To avoid the Index Recheck you need a (much!) larger setting for work_mem.

@FrankHeikens after set larger work_mem, the sql becomes faster but still slow even there is not any lossy

Also, why I increased the size of shared_buffer but the shared buffer hit becomes lower?
